# How to watch the progress of the track using Howler.js

Tags: javascript, howler.js

I am trying to use Howler.js. i wan to know if there is any method that updates the duration ot track played till now. Or do I need to use setInterval/requestAnimationFrame for this by myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs, man: https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js#seekseek-id

Looks like `seek` without any arguments should get you what you need.

Comment: seek is not an observsble i think.